# OpenLDAP field values within a list

Tags: openldap

I have set an openLDAP server and I have created a custom schema with various fields and it's working perfectly fine. However, I have some fields which I would like to only have some values.
For example, I have a field called `deviceLocation` and I only want to have the values of `EAST`, `WEST` or `CENTER`.
How can I make this?

Comment: I may be missing something, but wouldn't that in part be a matter of how data is put into LDAP? I can't find anything to suggest it is possible to configure openLDAP to look into the values of objects, but you can restrict who is able to set a given field - maybe ensuring only a specific person, department, or script can populate/modify those fields is one approach?

Comment: i don't understand exactly what you say, but openLDAP can check the values you are putting into the server when you create a new entry, so you can restrict the values a field can have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `constraints` overlay to your configuration. It allows you to add regular expressions that the values must match to be accepted by add or change operations. Alternatively, it would allow you to create a subtree with all allowed locations and then check if th value you try to add is listed in that subtree.

http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Constraints

Answer (score 1):

For future reference: as @Sven indicated, i used constraints to solve the problem. In my case, I create one ldif file to activate the constraint module:

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: constraint.la
```

And another one to configure it:

```
dn: olcOverlay=constraint,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConstraintConfig
olcOverlay: constraint
olcConstraintAttribute: deviceLocation regex ^(EAST|WEST|CENTER)$
```

Uploaded the files with `ldapadd` and worked like a charm

Comment: `deviceLoacation` looks like a typo